# Servir dos aplicaciones Angular5 en Expressjs

Tags: express, angular4

Estoy montando un servidor con express el que quiero servir una API rest y dos aplicaciones Angular5.

Tengo delante un proxy nginx que redirige el trafico a la aplicación express, transformando las peticiones http a https.

La estructura de directorios es:

```
servidor.js (Apliacion express)
    ├── api
    ├── app1
    │   ├──index.html
    │   ├──assets
    │   └──*.js y *.css
    └── app2
        ├──index.html
        ├──assets
        └──*.js y *.css
```

En el servidor express tengo:

```
require('./api/index')(app);

const options = { extensions: ['html', 'js', 'css'],
                 maxAge: '1d',
                 setHeaders: res => res.set('x-timestamp', Date.now() )}
app.use('/app1', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/app1'), options));
app.use('/app2', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/app2'), options));        

app.get('/app1', (req, res) => {
    res.type('html'); 
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app1/index.html');
});

app.get('/app2', (req, res) => {
    res.type('html'); 
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app2/index.html');
});
```

La API me responde correctamente.

/ me responde con la app1.

/app1 me responde con la app1.

el problema lo tengo con app2 ya que /app2 me responde con el html correcto de app2 pero con los siguientes errores en la carga de los js y los css:

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://midominio.com/styles.9c0ad73….bundle.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
midominio.com/:1 GET https://midominio.com/inline.8f40296….bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
midominio.com/:1 GET https://midominio.com/polyfills.f20484b….bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
midominio.com/:1 GET https://midominio.com/main.56d2be6….bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
```

Y todavía mejor, necesitaría recoger parametros de la url para acceder directamente a rutas internas de la aplicación.

Por ejemplo: https://midominio.com/app2/zona/25

Alguien puede hecharme una mano con esto?.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Me autorespondo para que conste en futuras consultas del hilo.

Copio los fichero de las carpetas /dist de las dos aplicaciones a /app1.

!!! Ojo !!! Cambio el nombre del indes de la app2 por app2.html

En el raiz de las rutas de app1 tengo /admin y /gestion, por lo que defino esas dos rutas en el express.

En el raiz de las rutas de app2 tengo varias rutas y defino las mismas en express, pero diciendole que carge el index renombrado.

Por último defino una carpeta estatica donde tengo los 2 html y todos los js y css de las aplicaciones.

De esta forma:

```
servidor.js (Apliacion express)
    ├── api
    └─── app1
       ├──index.html
       ├──app2.html    
       ├──assets
       └──*.js y *.css
```

Y el contenido de servidor.js:

```
require('./api/index')(app);    

app.get('/gestion', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app1/index.html');
});    

app.get('/admin', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app1/index.html');
});    

app.get('/zona/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app2.html');
});

app.get('/tipo/:id', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app2.html');
});

.......

const options = { extensions: ['html', 'js', 'css', 'ico'],
                 maxAge: '1d',
                 setHeaders: res => res.set('x-timestamp', Date.now() )}

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/app1'), options));
```